# GET to CSS returns 404

Tags: html, css, express

So I recently moved my website from a single-page website to an express server. Now I changed the file paths, but I cannot get my css and js files to load.

As seen in the developer console, the GET request to `https://<website>.com/public/css/main.css` returns a 404.

This is the css link:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/main.css">`

This is my server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const getpages = require('./router/getpages.js');

app.use('/', getpages);

app.use(express.static('public'));

// 404's
app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('Page not found or non-existant.<br><br><a href="/">Home</a>');
});

app.listen(3000, console.log('Running on port 3000'));
```

This is `./router/getpages.js`:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const path = require('path');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/', 'index.html'));
})

module.exports = router;
```

This is the file structure:

[image: file structure]

*Note, I could not find any other questions that helped me, before this is marked as a dupe again.*

Comment: Hey JJJ, I am unsure why you edited my question: removed 'So', and removed the Note I added. Also I am unsure why this question deserves a downvote. Your edits seem pretty useless to me. It'd be awesome if you could cast your reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from the documentation, you should not have `public` in the route

`https://<website>.com/css/main.css` should work as expected.

refer : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

> For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and
>   JavaScript files in a directory named public:
>
> `app.use(express.static('public'))`
>
> Now, you can load the files that are
>   in the public directory:
>
> eg : http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
>
> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
>   name of the static directory is not part of the URL.